# Is the interface method capable of returning a generic type?

Tags: java, generics, interface

Is the interface method capable of returning a generic type?
Will this code work?

```
public interface Parametrizable<T> {
    public T createSomeObject(T n);
}
```

Comment: Why wouldn't it? Though depending on what you want, you may want to pass a `Class<T>` instead.

Comment: Did you mean kind of that? 
public interface Parametrizable<T> {
    public Class<T> createSomeObject(T n);
}

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/ aka **try**'ing it out. Would have given you a faster answer too, rather than wasting time writing question and waiting here for someone to answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a word - yes. This is actually pretty common, and even the JDK has such methods - consider, e.g., [`List#get`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#get-int-).